# How I can get sum all values custom field mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema:

```js
{
 userName: String
 postCount: Number,
 commentCount: Number,
 abuseCount: Number,
}
```

I need get sum all users counts all fields in result

example

```js
{
 "userName": "John"
 "postCount": 5,
 "commentCount": 1,
 "abuseCount": 4,
}, {
 "userName": "Bob"
 "postCount": 11,
 "commentCount": 41,
 "abuseCount": 3,
}, {
 "userName": "Alex"
 "postCount": 2,
 "commentCount": 15,
 "abuseCount": 6,
}
```

result must be ~

```js
    {
     "postCount": 18, (sum all postCount field users)
     "commentCount": 57,
     "abuseCount": 10,
    }
```

How I can do this? Thx!

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621300/how-to-sum-the-value-of-a-key-across-all-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection

Comment: Try `db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: null,
           postCount: { $sum: "$postCount" },
           commentCount: { $sum: "$commentCount" },
          abuseCount:{$sum: "$abuseCount" }
         }
     }
   ]
)`

Comment: oh guy, are you know, if I have 1 boolean field in my schema, can I sum all  true values??