# Sum from multiple collections in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections i.e. col1 and col2 .
**col1 has fields like:**
*_id

user

payout*
**Col2 reads like**
*_id

user

amount*

I want output to be sum of payout *(from col1)* and amount *(from col2)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just find the data in both collections and then pass both objects into a function thats adds to the sum? 
something like this:

`var sum = 0;
    //do this for both collections
    db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(obj){
        sum+=obj.payout; 
    });`

if what you wanted to do was get the overall sum forEach different user you could do something like this:

`var sumForUser = {};
    //do this for both collections
    db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(obj){
        if ( sumForUser[obj.user] ) {
            sumForUser[obj.user] += obj.payout;
        else 
            sumForUser[obj.user] = obj.payout;
    });`

then you would a "sumForUser" object with the sum you wanted for every user. this you would be a "map" of user to sum.

this could also be done in many different ways, including use of reduce functions and other mongoDB functions such as MapReduce and so on. 
maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how) can be of help. also [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621300/how-to-sum-the-value-of-a-key-across-all-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection).

Comment: Can you please explain further? Each collection has multiple entries by same user

Comment: what is your expected output? the sum of amount and payout per user? or the total amount and payout for every one?

Comment: Sum of all payouts and amounts of a user together